# Why don't Ikaros & Tomoki use more the Transport Cards to solve their problems?

Tags: sora-no-otoshimono

Even thought in the first episode, Ikaros used her cards to accord every single desire of Tomoki, bringing to what looks like the end of the world, then the use of those is reduced to 2 times (I may have forgotten one or two occurrence(s)).

> - Episode 2 : Not intentionnaly when Tomoki wishes to make Sohara's underwears fly away unless it is the underwear Tomoki wants;
> - Episode 4 : Sohara borrows a card from Ikaros to bring all the panties in Tomoki's house to explode, Tomoki should look at them or touch them.

Why didn't Tomoki use more those cards to grant him what he wished?

Even if you take apart the opportunity of destroying/neutralizing Chaos by a single wish, he could have used it in some similar issues of the one mentionned above. Just as an example :

> In episode 9, Tomoki spots an erotic DVD at a booth, but cannot afford it because Ikaros broke some other item.

It would be logical from Tomoki to use a card to get this DVD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In episode 2 Tomoki can't use the cards to stop it because, a masters choices are absolute. Cards can't undo what other cards have done. And in the manga it says you can't use the same Transport twice, thats also the reason why tomoki has a limited amount of money, even though he got so much in the first episode.

And if you're thinking now that in the first episode this was not like it, well they made it a dream, they didn't undo the card.

Episode 4: the same reason, and Tomoki hadn't any cards near him to teleport away or something like that.

Episode 9: Even though Tomoki is a pervert, he would never wan't Ikaros to do pervertet Stuff, so he doesn't wan't her to get the dvd for him

The autors actually thought about this things, but you only see it if you read the manga, because in the anime there are to many scenes witch don't exist.

Comment: Hope my answer was helpfull, and sorry for the bad english :D

Comment: I'm not sure to get it, because Tomoki wished everything that happend in ep.1 was just a dream, it did change the cards nature? Do they mention the change in the manga? :) Also "He would never wan't Ikaros to do pervert stuff", in the ep1 also, he used Ikaros cards for this kind of ideas, but as @thePiGrepper suggested, it is possible that "Tomoki learned that he shouldnt use the cards for trivial stuff". Interesting anwser tho!

Comment: It's better explained in the manga, and no it didn't change the cards nature: Tomoki just set it all to a dream, he didn't undo or change what happened. I don't think you saw season 2 and the movies, so go ahead and watch it, then you'll realize that tomoki doesn't want Ikaros to do anything pervertet himselfe. He loves Ikaros (Not in the I love you, lets be together forever way) from deep down in his heart, and he wants her to stay pure. Thats also why in season to he goes to this temple, shrine thingy to clean up his mind. Hope you understand what im trying to say. Ps SoNoOt is MyFavAnime :D

Comment: Yeah you're right about the temple part. What disturbs me is the part about not using the card twice while they do it ALL the time with the same card in the first episode. And yeah it's a great one!

Comment: I don't mean they can't use the new card  models twice. If you look at the things cards do as "magical spells", they can't do the same spell twice. But some cards (the newer models) are able to do more than one spell.

Comment: Oh okay. Accepted then!

Comment: By the way, do you know when the second part of the secon movie is comming out?

Comment: Didn't watch the movies already! If you want to keep discussing, consider joining the [main discution room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-) ;)

Comment: Okay, i'll consider it. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, I think many can agree that SoraOto is a series which displays a comedy side and a serious side, and sometimes (many times actually) the comedic parts, like the first episode for example, serves, in the best case, for character development and, in the worst case, just for laughs. Most of the information thrown at us in the comedy parts aren't really used on the serious parts, especially when it comes to plot solving. I personally think it is just the author's decision NOT to do this.

Also, I think that at the end of episode one, Tomoki learned that he shouldn't use the cards for trivial stuff, especially after everything that happened in that first episode. Maybe that was actually the author stating why everything shouldn't be solved by a deus ex machina-like device.

Comment: Yeah I guess you're right for the first part, was just searching if there was a "rationnal" explanation :) Even if you can't use the synapse against itself, in the DVD example I gave, it would still have been possible tho!

Comment: hmm, yeah that's true, it would have been possible. but i think that at the end of episode one, Tomoki learned that he shouldnt use the cards for trivial stuff, especially after everything that happened in that first episode. Maybe, that was actually the author stating why everything shouldnt be solved by a deus ex machina-like device.

Comment: "Tomoki learned that he shouldnt use the cards for trivial stuff" Actually that's kind of a great idea, you should add it on the answer!

Comment: Ok, I added that last part and deleted the other reason becsuse it didnt applied to your particular example.